# c# Program crashes when redirecting standard output, due to Console.SetWindowSize

Tags: c#

I have a closed source application that outputs information into the standard output that I want to read. I wrote a program with the following code:

```
_proc = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("blablubb") 
{ 
  CreateNoWindow = true, 
  RedirectStandardOutput = true, 
  UseShellExecute = false, 
  WorkingDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(Settings.User) 
});
```

However, the started application crashes with this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.
  at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
  at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
  at **System.Console.SetWindowSize(Int32 width, Int32 height)**
  at Core.Main(String[] args)
```

It runs fine without my little program.

Comment: So, guessing by your "closed source" comment you aren't willing to show us the code for the process that is being started....

Comment: Sure, CreateNoWindow = true is a poison-pill for a program that calls Console.SetWindowSize().  You'll have to stop doing that or use a telephone to ask the author of the program to post a question to SO.

Comment: @konkked I do not have the source, which is why i am not showing it
I could ask the author but that would take days :S

Comment: @HansPassant even without CreateNoWindow it crashes. The redirected standard output is causing it

Comment: I solved it by disassembling the closed source program with ildasm, removing the setWindowSize and reassembling it with ilasm. Not a perfect solution but good enough for now

Comment: Just make sure it's allowed by the software license. Most licenses don't allow you to make a modification like this. It's a shame when a software can't handle some scenario like this (i.e. not having a console window - I guess the author never tried what happens when running `foo > x.x`), but that doesn't usually give you the right to "fix" the problem on your own.

Comment: @Luaan true, will look that up